Why do we need to specify the object in std::bind() to describe it as a functor?
I have been getting started with ROS and came across the following subscriber code:-
#include <memory>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"
using std::placeholders::_1;

class MinimalSubscriber : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  MinimalSubscriber()
  : Node("minimal_subscriber")
  {
    subscription_ = this->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>(
      "topic", 10, std::bind(&MinimalSubscriber::topic_callback, this, _1));
  }

private:
  void topic_callback(const std_msgs::msg::String::SharedPtr msg) const
  {
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I heard: '%s'", msg->data.c_str());
  }
  rclcpp::Subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>::SharedPtr subscription_;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<MinimalSubscriber>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}

My confusion is specifically regarding the syntax
subscription_ = this->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>(
      "topic", 10, std::bind(&MinimalSubscriber::topic_callback, this, _1));

As per my understanding, this is a ROS node to keep subscribing messages of type string from the Topic named "topic" and execute the topic_callback() whenever there is a new message. Coming from a very raw background, I wanted to ask why do we even need to use the bind() function? Can't we simply pass topic_callback function or a pointer to that, as an argument (Probably like Python) ?
And why do we need to specify "this"? When we are referencing the topic_callback, it makes sense only if there exists an MinimalSubscriber object whose member function is topic_callback, so again specifying this seems to be redundant. Same for _1, there's only 1 argument being passed, i.e. String. According to me instead of bind, this->topic_callback could have been passed.
I am probably wrong at several fronts. I did look at this excellent answer:-
std::bind(), but couldn't grasp it completely.

"only if there exists an MinimalSubscriber object whose member function is topic_callback": And what if there are many? How should std::bind know on which of these you want to call the function? The purposes of a class is to have multiple instances of it in the program.

In C++ there is a fundamental difference between regular functions and non-static class functions (aka methods). A pointer to a method is not the same type as a pointer to a function, and a pointer to a method cannot be called without a separately supplied object to call it on. I guess Python does some work behind the scenes to make sure you can combine a method pointer and an object as a single entity, C++ requires you to use std::bind or std::function.

@john this is where I am a bit confused. So a method should exist only if the object is defined. Correct? Moreover, we are accessing a method of the same class. So, when I define a MinimalSubscriber object, it should refer to its own method by default. Alternatively, what could be a way to access method of some different object in the class, if I chose not to specify "this"?

@Manish No, method pointers exist independently of any object (just like regular pointers exist independently of anything to point to).

@Manish (object.*method_ptr)(parameters) or (object_ptr->*method_ptr)(parameters) are the two ways to call a method via a method pointer

@Manish Strictly speaking these are not method pointers but pointers-to-members, since the same syntax can be used to access class data members as well, although this is very rarely used.

@john I see. Makes more sense now. Thanks!

@Manish Also note that non-static member function pointers are not actually pointers in C++. Even though we call them pointers, they're not.

Also refer to the dupe How std::bind works with member functions and Using std::bind with member function, use object pointer or not for this argument?

@user12002570 thanks for the resources. I came across this for the first time. Will have a detailed look into it.

This problem is not ROS specific. Consider that you have a function that accepts a callback returning void and taking 1 std::string argument:
void foo(std::function<void(std::string)> callback) {
    if (callback) {
        callback("foo");
    }
}

If you have a free function void freeFun(std::string), you can pass it directly foo(freeFun);, however if you have a class or struct:
struct Foo {
    void bar(std::string str) {
        std::cout << "bar str = " << str << "\n";
    }
    static void baz(std::string str) {
        std::cout << "baz str = " << str << "\n";
    }
    void registerCallback();
};

then you cannot simply use bar as argument, because bar needs an object of type Foo to be called on. So:
using namespace std::placeholders;
int main() {
    // foo(&Foo::bar);  // nope
    foo(&Foo::baz); // ok, because static method doesn't need associated object
    Foo myFoo;
    foo(std::bind(&Foo::bar, &myFoo, _1));  // ok, but rarely used for practical reasons
}

void Foo::registerCallback() {
    foo(std::bind(&Foo::bar, this, _1));  // ok, typical use-case
}

std::bind transforms function bar that (informally) has a signature void bar(Foo*, std::string) to an object that internally holds "bound" arguments, and that can be called like a function with signature void f(std::string).
The same could be achieved using lambda expression
foo([this](std::string str) { bar(str); });

or a generic lambda if you don't want to be bothered with argument type:
foo([this](auto str) { bar(str); });


'foo(std::bind(&Foo::bar, &myFoo, _1));  // ok, but rarely used for practical reasons '-> This is what I had in mind. Do you mind expanding a bit more on what are the practical reasons? Also, didn't understand the registerCallback() logic. It is not expecting any arguments, right? However, when you define it after main(), it executes foo, which in turn is expecting a string to execute bar.

Sure, std::bind(&Foo::bar, &myFoo, _1) is not very practical, because you need to make sure yourself that the object myFoo lives longer than the "registery" where your callback is "registered". If you call the callback after myFoo is destroyed - then it is UB. In my example it will not happen, because foo executes callback immediately and returns, but typical use-case for "register callback" is to store it somewhere and call later.

In case of std::bind(&Foo::bar, this, _1) usually you have "registering" login in class constructor (or some init function), and a "deregistering" logic in class destructor, to make sure callbacks are not called on a dead object. Or class Foo makes sure that the system where callbacks were registered is stopped before Foo destruction. In your example subscription_ is probably the object responsible for removing the callback, and it is destroyed before its parent class.

"(...) which in turn is expecting a string to execute bar" - yes; std::bind(&Foo::bar, this, _1) creates a new functor that accepts std::string as argument. This functor is passed to foo as argument. foo calls this functor with std::string argument equal to "foo". Functor internally calls Foo::bar with first argument Foo* equal to this and second argument std::string equal to "foo".

Perfect! This has helped me a lot. Thank you!
